# Blocking function in a loop

Tags: c

What happens if we put a blocking function in a loop in C program? For example:
I have a function named `os_io_read()` which basically reads the serial (RS232) input buffer and waits till we have some input in that buffer sourced from some other device. Now if I put this function in a `for(;;)` loop, is it still going to wait for the data or the loop will continue. In my case I have a  hardware device running Linux OS and the hardware goes to ERROR mode if I try to execute a C program in the mentioned way.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: putting it in a loop will NOT change its behavior

Comment: blocking call is always wait for event, it doesn't matter where you call.. in case of loop does same operation repeatedly.. Kind of deadlock.

Comment: @ThiruShetty: Does that mean that the for loop won't continue until the blocking function returns?

Comment: @Navneet  yes, loop will continue only after blocking function returns, then  executes rest of the statements in the loop, then next iteration,  but  it is not deadlock

Comment: @ShivYaragatti i mean to say infinite loop and doesn't allow other things to execute for ever.

Comment: @Thiru Shetty,  right for(;;) infinite loop but we can't say it as deadlock, deadlock means nothing is working, but here loop is working as expected by calling blocking function, all process or event handles will be in infinte loop all the time(throughout process life time), if we call  infinite loop as deadlock it would mislead understanding of things,  if it doesn't allow others to run that we call as CPUHOG not deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

If `os_io_read()` blocks it blocks. Putting it in a `for` loop will not affect this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it in a loop it will do its job repeatetly. The loop does not affedt whats inside of it in any way.

Normally if handling a problem that comes with a sort of "realtime" aspect it is a good idea to not use blocking - so you have always the control. Use non-blocking instead and check the return-codes if it read something or just returned by no data.